# footer is not visible in qweb report

Tags: odoo-8, wkhtmltopdf, qweb

I have used the custom header & footer in qweb report ,In my report header is visible,but footer is not visible.Please help me

Odoo version-8.00, wkhtmltopdf version-0.12.2.1(with patched qt)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<openerp>
<data>
<template id="report_myreport">
<t t-call="report.html_container">
    <t t-foreach="docs" t-as="o">
           <div class="header">
                <div class="row" style="border-bottom: 1px solid black;">
                   <div class="col-xs-2">
                        <img t-if="company.logo" t-att-src="'data:image/png;base64,%s' % company.logo" style="height:120px; width:180px;"/>
                   </div>
               </div>
            </div>

            <div class="page">

        This is my Page

            </div> 
    <div class="footer">
        <div class="text-center" style="border-top: 1px solid black;">
                <p class="list-inline">

                this my footer 
            </p>
            <p>Phone: +917455462155 | Email: example@gmail.com </p>             
        </div>
    </div> 
        </t>
    </t>
  </template>
  </data>
  </openerp>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried the recommended wkhtmltopdf version?

https://www.odoo.com/documentation/8.0/setup/install.html
wkhtmltopdf ... The recommended version is 0.12.1